# Converting sympy point object to tuple of coordinates

Tags: python, sympy

I'm working on a project in which I'm using sympy to (among other things) find the midpoint between two points in a 2D image. Since midpoint gives me a sympy point object, how can I convert this to a simple tuple of the coordinates?

EDIT: here's what I have:

```
vertex = Segment(hipL, hipR).midpoint
vertex = tuple(vertex)
```

Here's the error I'm getting:
    TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

EDIT 2: changed to this:

```
vertex = Point(hipL).midpoint(hipR)
vertex = tuple(vertex)
```

Seems to be working.

Comment: `>>>from sympy.geometry import Point` `>>>tuple(Point(1,2))` try this

Comment: No luck. I edited my post with the relevant code snippet. hipL and hipR are both tuples containing coordinates on the image.

Comment: It seems that `midpoint` is a method of the `Segment` object which you have to *call* to get a result. So change `.midpoint` to `.midpoint()`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is an attribute not a method

Comment: `tuple(Segment((0,0), (2,2)).midpoint)` gives me `(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tuple`:

```
from sympy import Point, Segment
a = Point(2, 3)
b = Point(3, 7)
print(tuple(a.midpoint(b)))
print(tuple(Segment(a, b).midpoint))
```

prints the tuple `(5/2, 5)` twice in SymPy 1.3. If it does not work for you, update SymPy.